# Android: Open PLS-File for MediaPlayer includes same streaming link which opens the PLS file?! Error (1,-2147483648)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, shoutcast

I'm working at a streaming app for Android and just faceing a strange error. My streaming urls are saved in a database which also includes m3u and pls files. These files are parsed for the streaming url which works fine. (I only check if the streaming-url contains m3u or pls)

Now I just found out, that some of the links don't work in the MediaPlayer. For example: A station has following streaming link `http://drumstep-aacp.rautemusik.fm` If I open the link in my MediaPlayer it throws an `Error (1,-2147483648)` (usually unsupported file format).

If I open the same link in a browser, I'm redirected to the file `http://drumstep-aacp.rautemusik.fm/listen.pls`. (This is the reason for 2147483648 Error I guess)

Since I already wrote a PLS-Parser, this is not really a problem, but the PLS-File looks like

```
[playlist]
File1=http://drumstep-aacp.rautemusik.fm  //same link I entered at the beginning
Title1=#Musik.DrumStep
Length1=-1
NumberOfEntries=1
Version=2
```

If I would try opening the stream link again, this would start an endless loop. So how can I open that stream? (Another example is http://jam-aacp.rautemusik.fm)

The examples are shoutcast links, as far as I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here comes down to the request headers.  This server is using some crafty detection of browsers and non-browsers to help determine whether or not to redirect you to the real stream URL or not.

If you make a request for http://jam-aacp.rautemusik.fm/ with this header, you will get the `.pls` file:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Now, if you request the same URL without this header, you get a 302 redirect to the actual stream URL at `http://80.237.157.12:12005/`.

This server at 80.237.157.12:12005 is running SHOUTcast, which has its own detection.  Instead of `Accept` header though, it uses `User-Agent`.  If the user-agent string contains "`Mozilla`", then the server will send you the admin interface.  Otherwise, it will send you the stream data.

In short, you need to make your requests without an `Accept` header, and with a `User-Agent` that does not contain `Mozilla`.  By the way, you can easily figure this out yourself and reproduce the problem by downloading a copy of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).

Comment: thanks brad, you pushed me in the right direction! now let's see how to set a different user-agent in the setDataSource() from MediaPlayer..